# Specific rights for a role in symfony 3

Tags: permissions, symfony, role

i am a newbie in the Symfony framework and I have to create a web application. The problem I have is the autorization of defined actions in the code.

I load my users out of a database with some roles (many-to-many). In the security.yml I work with ACLs for the different routes. But now my teacher told me, that I should implement specific rights to roles. That means, that I have some roles with rights (many-to-many), so I can create new roles with simply adding the some rights.
An example might be "editing users" in the database. So I can specify granually the rights "editing", "persisting" and so on.

How can I implement this in my Controllers/Twig-Templates? In Twig I work with the isGranted()-function, there I can only check roles?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Start with custom security voters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! So I don't know whether I have understood this right. The logic, where I say, which user can for example "edit" a post, is in the Voter? So in this example in the canView() nand canEdit()-functions? And in this functions I could take some data from my database? I want to create a table ROLE and RIGHT with a many-to-many-relationship. So I would take all specific rights from the roles of the current user and if they match I would return true in the canEdit()/canView()-functions?

Comment: Yes, your voter can access the database.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is that the right architecture for linking permissions to roles? I would link a user to roles and a role to specific (hardcoded) rights. In the Voter I would load all specific rights because I know the roles of the user. And with the information of the rights I can decide whether I grant the access or not.